# how to bootup/reboot in verbose mode?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub2, boot-loader

I have Ubuntu 14.04TLS. How can I permanently change grub to switch to verbose mode on bootup/reboot so I can see the rolling text? I would like to make this change stick. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts

Comment: I always love to see the verbose scrolling text, It feels like I am on a space ship or similar..!! Feels much geeky

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would need to edit the file `/etc/default/grub`. In this file you'll find an entry called `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. This entry must be edited to control the display of the splash screen.

The presence of the word `splash` in this entry enables the splash screen, with condensed text output. Adding `quiet` as well, results in just the splash screen; which is the default for the desktop edition since 10.04 (Lucid Lynx). In order to enable the "normal" text start up, you would remove both of these.

So, the default for the desktop, (i.e. splash screen only):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

For the traditional, text display:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
```

After editing the file, you need to run `update-grub`.

```
sudo update-grub
```

For more details, see this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2